# DynamoDBTypeConvertedJson property order for keys

Tags: json, amazon-dynamodb

I'm working with a DDB that converts a item using the DynamoDBMapper to the partition key by using DynamoDBTypeConvertedJson.

So for example:

```
public class TestObject{
   private int id;
   private String name;
}

@DynamoDBTable(tableName = TestTable.TABLE_NAME)
public class DynamoDBTestItem{
   private testObj;

@DynamoDBIndexHashKey(globalSecondaryIndexName = TestTable.TEST_INDEX)
@DynamoDBTypeConvertedJson
public TestObject getTestObject() {
    return testObject;
}

public void setTestObject(TestObject testObj) {
    this.testObj = testObj;
}
}
```

It seems like DynamoDBTypeConvertedJson is based on Jackson JSON, which by default does not keep the property order. Thus, we can save items either as

```
{\"id\":7,\"name\":\"ObjName\"} or {\"name\":ObjName,\"id\":\"7\"}
```

When I query the database, I do infact see that some records have id first and some have name first.

Now, when I do the following:

```
DynamoDBTestItem hashKey = new DynamoDBTestItem;
hashKey = new TestObj(7, "ObjName");
            DynamoDBQueryExpression<DynamoDBTestItem> expression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<DynamoDBTestItem>()
                .withIndexName(TestTable.TEST_INDEX)
                .withHashKeyValues(hashKey)
                .withConsistentRead(false);
```

What I'm curious about is if this query would ever result in a missed hit because the JSON property order was not preserved. So if "id" came before "name" in the saved entry, but when we go to query, the JSON decides to put "name" before "id", would that result in a missed query hit?

It seems like theoretically this would happen, but I haven't seen it happen in this system which is why I'm curious. Is the system just getting lucky here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@DynamoDBTypeConvertedJson` annotation ([source code](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBTypeConvertedJson.java)) uses fasterxml jackson ObjectMapper, for which the default setting is to [sort properties alphabetically](http://static.javadoc.io/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.1/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/MapperFeature.html#SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY) (with some caveats which are mentioned in the linked documentation).

In the case you have described, the ordering will always be the same, but it is possible to create a case where the ordering is not consistent.